# Connecting to RDS Postgres via jdbc & c3p0 unable to acquire from the underlying database

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds, jdbc

Trying to connect from an application using C3P0 and the latest Postgresql JDBC driver 9.4.1211.

We want the connection string to be SSL and have an MD5 hash password on the user account:

```
c3p0 {
  jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://myserver.rds.amazonaws.com/MyDatabase?ssl=true"
  user = MyAccount
  password = MyPassword
  testConnectionOnCheckout = true
}
```

The server has generated SSL certificates,which have been referenced in the parameter group, along with `ssl = 1`.

The certificate has been added into the JVM `cacerts`

What we are getting an error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0Pcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPool

We can use the same account to connect successfully via psql and pgadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it seems c3p0 drops the ssl=true from the connection string.  The ssl setting has to be coded into the properties object for the connection.